# AJAX Call with gulp/browser-sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, gulp, browser-sync

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : '/img',
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                        if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|JPG|png|gif)$/) ) {
                            imgArray.push(val);
                        }
                });
                bsServer();
            }
    });
});
```

I'm using the included code block to draw images out of an 'img' directory, pushing them into a javascript array to be iterated over in another function. When running on http-server and python servers, this function works great, but in trying to run this AJAX call on certain servers (e.g., browser-sync, Github-Pages), I get a 404 (Not Found) error.

I've tried all variations on the file path that I can think of and I cannot seem to get it going. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: same origin policy? also, there may be csrf protections in place. check your network tab.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I'm looking at jsonp to get around SOP stuff at the moment, but am a bit confused at how to implement in this case

Comment: jsonp only works when you control the response. try node and "request" npm as no restrictions are there on client  and is javascript that you understand

Comment: and you can use jquery npm on node too